# No lxml Wheel for Linux?

Tags: python, lxml, python-wheel, pep

The lxml project has decided to not provide a Wheel for lxml on Linux:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/1176147

I am neither an expert on PEP 427 or lxml's dependencies, so I'm hoping someone can explain why or why not the lxml team's concerns around providing a Wheel are valid?

lxml is 95+% of my build time, so I'm very interested in options to speed it up, and a Wheel seems like the official option.

Answer (score 1):

[lxml 3.6.3+](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/) provides binary wheels (`manylinux1_x86_64` platform tag -- see [PEP-513 that also describes some issues with this approach](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0513/)) i.e., `pip install lxml` can work without compiling `lxml` from source on many Linux (AMD64) systems.

Check whether your linux distribution provides a binary package such as `sudo apt-get install python3-lxml` (unrelated to wheels).